# Unable to write a new DataFrame into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a new dataframe into the CSV file. But it is not being written into the file(empty file) neither giving any error.

I feel the issue is with this line. Since I am trying to write a single value to the column.

```
order['trade_type'] = trade_type
```

Any idea what's wrong here.

```
def write_transaction_to_file(trade_type):
    order = pd.DataFrame()
    order['trade_type'] = trade_type
    order.to_csv("open_pos.csv", sep='\t', index=False)


write_transaction_to_file('SELL')
```

Comment: Your code does work and it saves an empty dataframe with just the column `trade_type`. If you want to generate the row with the value 'SELL' you'll need to run`write_transaction_to_file(['SELL'])`. Check your current directory to get to know where Python is saving your dataframe.

Comment: Is it just a test? What is the point in writing a dataframe with one column and one row?

Comment: @Valentino no, this is a part of the project. To keep things simple, I have pasted the code which is having the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates an **empty** DataFrame, without even column names.

And now look at `order['trade_type'] = trade_type`.

If *order* contained some rows, among columns there were one named just
*'trade_type'* (string) and *trade_type* (variable) was a scalar,
then in all rows in *order* would receive this value (in this column).

But since *order* contains **no rows**, there is no place to write to.

Instead you can **append** a row, e.g.:

```
order = order.append({'trade_type': trade_type}, ignore_index=True)
```

The rest of code is OK, the output file name as ordinary string
is also OK.

Other solution: Just create a DataFrame with a single row and single
named column, filled with your variable:

```
order = pd.DataFrame([[trade_type]], columns=['trade_type'])
```

Then write it to CSV file as before.